# Oracle SQL Developer 4.0 - How to remove double quotes in scripts

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm running Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.  When I script out a table, the owner, table name, column name, constraint name and etc are enclused with double quotes.  I looked through Tools -> Preferences and was not able to find any option to turn it off.  Does anyone know how to script a table without these quotes?

Thank you

Comment: Are they a problem? Personally I find them ugly, and they're not needed as long as you don't have mixed-case identifiers or anything else that requires quoting, but do they hurt in a script? Can you also clarify how you're generating this - from the 'SQL' tab when viewing a table, or via your own `dbms_metadata` commands?

Comment: When I click on the table, choose SQL tab, the script shown here contains double quotes.  Or when I right click on the table and choose Quick DDL, the quotes are also included here.

Comment: What I usually do is first check that there aren't any problematic identifiers (e.g. `"UglyCamelCase"`), and if there aren't any, I do a search-and-replace to remove the `"`s, and then highlight the code and repeatedly press Ctrl+' to change the case to the desired standard. Then I save the script and checked it into source control so I never have to do it again :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it using those methods. They are both using `dbms_metata.get_ddl` under the hood, it appears, and that [doesn't have an option to not quote identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66910). Looks like export uses that package too; data modeller has an option to quote identifiers but not sure if that's useful to you.

You can get rid of them by querying from a worksheet if you want though, as long as the DDL is less than 32K. With default settings:

```
create table t42 (id number, str varchar2(10)  default 'ABC',
  constraint t42_pk primary key (id));
create index i42 on t42(str);

set long 1000
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'T42', user) from dual;
select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('INDEX', 'T42', user) from dual;

  CREATE TABLE "STACKOVERFLOW"."T42" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "STR" VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'ABC', 
     CONSTRAINT "T42_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS"

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "STACKOVERFLOW"."T42_PK" ON "STACKOVERFLOW"."T42" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
  CREATE INDEX "STACKOVERFLOW"."I42" ON "STACKOVERFLOW"."T42" ("STR") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
```

With a little manipulation:

```
begin
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    'PRETTY', false);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    'CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER', true);
  dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.SESSION_TRANSFORM,
    'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
end;
/

select replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'T42', user), '"', null)
from dual;
select replace(dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('INDEX', 'T42', user), '"', null)
from dual;

  CREATE TABLE STACKOVERFLOW.T42 (ID NUMBER, STR VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'ABC') ;
  ALTER TABLE STACKOVERFLOW.T42 ADD CONSTRAINT T42_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE;

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX STACKOVERFLOW.T42_PK ON STACKOVERFLOW.T42 (ID) ;
  CREATE INDEX STACKOVERFLOW.I42 ON STACKOVERFLOW.T42 (STR) ;
```

Comment: Alex, thanks for the snippet.  It appears the get_dll() only provides the table structure and excludes things like indexes, constraints, defaults and etc.  Is there a way to get the complete script for the table?  Thanks!

Comment: @sydney - it should include constraints and defaults already. For indexes and other dependent objects you'll need to use other `dbms_metadata` calls. SQL Developer hides the complexity for you but is doing the same steps.

Comment: OK, I have to explore the sample you provided.  When I ran the get_dll earlier for a table, it did not include column constraints,

Comment: @sydney - you can choose to exclude or include them, but they should be included by default. Strange. You can see the options in the link in the answer.

Comment: I found an easier to way to do this.  I used Oracle Data Modeler.  I imported all the objects and generated the scripts.  This tool doesn't produce quotes.  Go figure ... :)

Comment: @sydney - I mentioned there's an option for using quoted identifiers for data modeller; it's off by default. (Tools->Preferences->Data Modeler->DDL; 6th checkbox *8-)